# How 'use index for order by' works in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

Would XK2_STOCK_QUOTE and XK4_STOCK_QUOTE be indexes that have already been created, or are they being created with this line? (QUOTE_SEQ_NBR and QUOTE_TIME are attributes in STOCK_QUOTE). Thank you

```
declare cur1 cursor for
select  *
    from  stockmarket.STOCK_QUOTE
               use index for order by  (XK2_STOCK_QUOTE,XK4_STOCK_QUOTE)
    order by  QUOTE_SEQ_NBR,QUOTE_TIME;
```

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT statement doesn't create indexes.

That SELECT statement with the index hint (in the question) is anticipating that an index named `XK2_STOCK_QUOTE` or `XK4_STOCK_QUOTE` already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `USE INDEX`.

Don't try to get two single-column indexes do the job of a "composite index"; declare this on the table:

```
INDEX(QUOTE_SEQ_NBR, QUOTE_TIME)
```